# Source that people are judged based on their inclinations

Tags: mussar-ethics, tzaddikim, evil-inclination

Where does the Orchos Tzaddikim say that everyone is judged according to their inclinations, meaning that you could have one person who acts better than a second person but the second person is better if they are going against their inclinations more? In other words, if one person has a tendency to be stingy and another person has a tendency to be kind, even though the person with the tendency to be kind may do more kindness, the one with the tendency to be stingy may be greater if he is going further against his natural tendency to be stingy?

I know this is true, I'm just trying to find the source in Orchos Tzaddikim (or if it isn't there I need to know which classical Mussar Sefer it was in). Thanks.

Comment: related: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/31625

Comment: לפום צערא אקרא. Is a mishna and the topic in orhchot tsadikim comes from chovot hallevavot